# Rails link_to :back redirect itself in a loop on form submission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6, but this should be applicable to any Rails version that supports the Rails back link with referrer. Here's the code:

```
# posts/new.html.erb
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
<%= form_with model: @post do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Here's the page flow:

1. Homepage -> View Post New -> Click Back -> Go back to Homepage
2. Homepage -> View Post New (/posts/new) -> Submit empty form -> Returns to Post New (/posts/new) with error (because validation fails) -> Click Back -> Goes back to Post New page (/posts/new) again -> Click Back -> Goes back to Post New page (/posts/new) again

On case 2, when I check the `href` of Back link, it keeps pointing back to `/posts/new`. This is due to referrer I think. But what is the workaround, so that it should go back to Homepage instead?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you don't redirect back when the user submits an invalid form - you render the view containing the form and send it back in the response body.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  # POST /posts
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      # renders the posts/new.html.erb template
      render :new
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

When the user submits the form they are send a non-idempotent POST request. You **should** show them the results of performing that action whether if it's creating a new resource (usually a redirect to the new resource) or by displaying the form again with errors.

You **should not** redirect back to the idempotent `GET /posts/new` route. That would require you to pass any parameters back as query string parameters or lose any user input.

This is not just a question of REST semantics or following conventions - this avoids the browser history issues that plague redirecting after a form submission and cache issues that could arise if you are using a reverse proxy to serve GET requests.